# How to remove part of ending string and update columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have strings in my table `Location` in column `PlaceForeign`:

```
SOMELONGTEXT - BERLIN - BERLIN
someOtherText - LUANDA - LUANDA
somethingsomething - PARIS - PARIS
```

I want to remove last occurrence of a city and to have like this:

```
SOMELONGTEXT - BERLIN
someOtherText - LUANDA
somethingsomething - PARIS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to *update*, then use:

```sql
UPDATE Location
SET PlaceForeign = SUBSTRING(PlaceForeign, 1, CHARINDEX('-', PlaceForeign, CHARINDEX('-', PlaceForeign) + 1) - 2);
```

The logic here is to take a substring from the start of the place until 2 characters before the occurrence of the *second* dash.

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9a1611b1423b3d1d8c888fa269e004c2) which uses a select to show that the substring logic is working.